# Measuring dissimilarity within the cluster - Kmodes

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, categorical-data

I was doing clustering with categorical data. I came across Kmodes algo and found it to be perfect for my requirements. Now, I want to measure dissimilarity within a cluster for all the clusters. I am thinking to measure the dissimilarity with a cluster and reduce it as much as possible. Is there any way to do that?
Alternatively, is there any way to check how efficiently my data has been clustered? 
Since my data is categorical, ways which consider distance as a metric might not be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To measure the dissimilarity within a cluster you need to come up with some kind of a metric. For categorical data, one of the possible ways of calculating dissimilarity could be the following:

```
d(i, j) = (p - m) / p
```

where:

- `p` is the number of classes/categories in your data
- `m` is the number of matches you have between samples `i` and `j`

For example, if your data has 3 categorical features and the samples, `i` and `j` are as follows:

```
    Feature1  Feature2  Feature3
i    x          y          z
j    x          w          z
```

So here, we have 3 categorical features, so `p=3` and out of these three, two features have same values for the samples `i` and `j`, so `m=2`. Therefore

```
d(i,j) = (3 - 2) / 3
d(i,j) = 0.33
```

Another alternative is to convert your categorical variables to one-hot-encoded features and then compute [jaccard simmilarity](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score.html).

So, in order to measure the dissimilarity within a cluster you could calculate pairwise dissimilarity between each object in your cluster and then take the average of that.

Based on these measures you may also use the [silhoutte score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) for evaluating the quality of your clustering  (but you need to take it with a grain of salt, sometimes the score can be good while the clustering might not be what you expected).

Comment: Nice. Is there any other way in which I can measure whether my clusters are optimal or not? I thought to calculate dissimilarity of each point in the cluster and reduce it to zero. I hope this works. Is there any way to validate that?

Comment: And also, can you please specify a bit more on what p is (in your proposed equation) ? Jaccard won't be a good idea as the purpose of using Kmodes will be ruled out (I am using that as everything in my dataset is categorical). Same goes with silhouette.

Comment: @Dhwani I added an example for the equation, hope it makes it more clear, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: For determining if the clustering is optimal or not, I guess what you are suggesting sounds fine. It's a subjective task and depends a lot on the data. Perhaps the best bet is your own judgement in the end. 

Also, you can use Jaccard similarity for categorical data, but you need to convert the categorical features into one hot encoded features. Something like the `get_dummies()` function in Pandas or the `OneHotEncoder` from sklearn can do that.